# unable to display string array

Tags: c++11, g++4.8

When i try to run this code, it compiles without any error, but i wanted that it should display the string and int array that it takes as input. Instead, after giving one input, I am presented with a list of zeroes and program terminates. 
however,when i removed the line containing k[j] from both for loops, it worked.
What am I doing wrong? Pardon if asked something stupid as I'm a novice, please help...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int t,count = 0;
string state[t];
int k[t];
cin>>t;
for (int j=0; j<t; j++)
{
getline(cin, state[j]);
cin>>k[j];
}
for (int j=0; j<t; j++)
{ cout<< state [j]<<'\t'<<k[j];
  cout<<endl;

}
return 0
}
```

Comment: Hint: `cin>>k[j]` leaves the trailing newline in the stream. You might find questions about similar issues here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You declare both arrays `k[]` and `state[]` with `t` wich is undefined at this moment.

`t` should be initiated with a valid value beforehand!

Comment: `t` isn't 0, its value is indeterminate. Reading it is Undefined Behaviour. Not to mention the fact that runtime-sized arrays are non-standard C++ (they're a GCC extension).

Comment: @Angew Verily.. only `count` is set to `0`.
I updated my answer.